# the true or false - closure, interior, with topology.Cl(A)=i(A) union A'

Tags: general-topology

I am studying general topology, and I know $cl(A)=A \cup A'$
and I also know $cl(A)= i(A) \cup b(A)$.

where A' is the set of limit points of A, cl(A) is closure, i(A) is interior of A, b(A) is boundary of A.

The question is....
I think $cl(A)=i(A) \cup A'$ is false but I can't find some counterexample.

Comment: $A'$ is the set of limit points?

Comment: The closure is the union of the interior and the boundary. It is also the union of the original set and the boundary. Is this what you're going for? (Your $A'$ notation is not standard.)

Comment: @Ian The notation $A'$ for the derivative of a set is standard enough for me, and also for [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)). It's $i(A)$ that's nonstandard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the space be the real line with the usual topology, and let $A=\{0\}.$ Then $\operatorname{cl}(A)=A$ since $A$ is closed, while $\operatorname{int}(A)\cup A'=\emptyset.$